# Returning Number of Arguments - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Is there a way to return the number of arguments in a Sub or Function in Access?

```
    Public Sub mySub(arg1 As String, Optional arg2 As Variant, Optional arg3 As Variant)
        'Some code
    End Sub
```

I would like to be able to return the number 3 from this Sub. Possible?

Comment: Do you need this during design time when you are coding or during runtime? Functions return values; subs don't. Use a function instead and just put `mySub = 3` in place of 'Some code.

Comment: I'm using it in a Sub that builds another Sub, so definitely not during runtime. It's not that big of a deal but I would like to grab that number just in case I wanted to add another argument to the Sub without hardcoding the value.

Comment: So you are using a function to write new code for you? Sounds novel, if not a little unusual to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the web site below they recommend using a Parameter array as the argument, which does not require that you know how many arguments.

Call your function: Function SomeProc(ParamArray avarItems() As Variant) and then within the function or procedure you work with the parameter array like any other array.  I think this would include the number of elements using Ubound(avarItems) + 1.  Only thing, the parameter array must be of type Variant, and it must be the last argument in the argument list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164533(v=office.10).aspx

Just to test this I created a little sample:

Option Explicit

Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim nCount1 As Integer

```
nCount1 = GetArgCount("one", "two", "three", "four")

MsgBox ("Arguments = " & nCount1)
```

End Sub
Function GetArgCount(ParamArray PassedArray() As Variant)

```
GetArgCount = UBound(PassedArray) + 1
```

End Function

This returns the number 4 in a msgbox()